# SQL Server Always On and Replication Merge

Tags: sql-server

How can replication Merge be done in a highly available environment? I tried to create the publisher in a partially contained database and it generates the error 21147 of sql,

Can the Express version of the SQL server be within a high availability group in the secondary nodes?

not have my database partially contained within a group of high availability that has consequences?

I hope you can help me with this topic, I thank you in advance for any contribution.

Comment: The answers to these questions will be dependent on the version of SQL Server you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the Express version of the SQL server be within a high availability group in the secondary nodes?

AlwaysON Availability groups **require** Enterprise edition. There are [basic Availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) for standard edition.

Also, partially contained db [do not support replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017#Limitations).

> Partially contained databases cannot use replication, change data capture, or change tracking.